# Method is undefined when importing from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm getting undefined when I try importing a method from another file. I have 3 files one calling the next.

**File1:**

```
const { methodFromFile2 } = require('./file2');
methodFromFile2('myParam');
```

**File2:**

```
const { methodFromFile3 } = require("../file3");

consoele.log(methodFromFile3); // undefined
function methodFromFile2(coolParam) {
    consoele.log(methodFromFile3); // undefined
}

module.exports = { methodFromFile2 };
```

**File3**

```
function methodFromFile3(coolParam) {
    ...
}

module.exports = { methodFromFile3 };
```

In file2, the method `methodFromFile3` is always undefined. But, when I move the required statement inside `methodFromFile2`, it works. Why is it that way and is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(require('../file3'));` in `file2.js`?

Comment: @blex An empty object

Comment: That would be impossible with the example you provided... Are you sure that the path of `../file3` is correct, and that `file3.js` does indeed export that? The issue is most probably in `file3`

Comment: @blex Ya, I copied and pasted it inside the `methodFromFile2` but it still didn't work

Comment: @blex In file one, `methodFromFile2('myParam');` is nested in an on function from socket.io. not sure if that makes a diff?

Comment: I don't think `file1` is relevant to the problem, as long as you see the output from your `console.log(methodFromFile3);` in your terminal. With the example provided, I don't see where the issue could be coming from, apart from what `file3.js` is actually exporting... sorry

Comment: Are there other `require()` statements you're not showing us in the real code?  This seems like it could be a circular require issue.

Comment: You have 2 typos for **console**  `consoele.log(methodFromFile3); // undefined` in file2, then if all are in the same folder it should work fine
tested here https://codesandbox.io/s/test-1-7f48p?file=/src/index.js:222-236

Comment: @jfriend00 Ya ur right! My first time hearing and running into this issue of circular require. I read up on it and was able to fix it. thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are other `require()` statements that you aren't showing us, then this is probably caused by a circular `require()` where A requires B and B requires A.  When you do that, one of the requires will end up getting an empty module object, not the one the module intends to return.